moment doing wrong calculations for day of the year
I am trying to find the day of the year using unix epoch and it returns 365 instead of the correct value. here is the code snippet
const momentY = moment(new Date(startDate))
    startDays = momentY.dayOfYear()

The value of startDate is: 1704081600000 which is Jan 1 2024. So this should return 1 not 365.
I am thinking this is some timezone issue as I store user-entered data by converting to (new Date()).getTime function. This is messing up my entire system. No matter from where user from mobile app stores begin of the year, how do I consistently get the same date when I use it for calculations?

This is your obligatory warning that momentjs is deprecated and you really shouldn't be using it.

didnt know. whats the replacement?

You could use date-fns or dayjs instead.

I just executed the function, I got 1 tho. I can't replicate this issue.

well, this is I think the timezone situation. Where this date got stored slightly different value for 1 jan 2024 at 12 am and in my timezone while testing it is off by a few hours,
